# Silverlight app always redownloads on Safari/Mac

Tags: macos, silverlight, safari

Our company has developed a silverlight application that I utilize on my Mac with Safari. The app itself works fine and behaves exactly as on the PC. However, every time I connect up to the site, the silverlight application downloads itself. On the PC this only happens when the development group made changes to the application.

Is there a setting on the Mac/Safari I should engage?  Is there something that needs to be set on the deployment side?  Anything in the code?

The application is reasonably large and therefore adds a considerable start up time for every download - not the best experience to have potential customers stare at a progress bar at the beginning of the talk...

Comment: Just answering my own question in the hope that it may help someone else: we determined that we were using a wild card certificate (*.mydomain.com) and that as a result of this Safari does not consider the site 'trusted' and continues to re-download the silverlight xap file.   So your options are to get a non-wild card based certificate and/or allow a call to http: instead of https: